# Why does math.sqrt work with a declared type of int?

Tags: java, integer, double

I know that type int cannot be treated as type double
I saw on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html, that Math.sqrt takes in double, I saw that the method signature for Math.sqrt is

```
sqrt(double a)
```

Why would this piece of code work(I tested it out) and compile?

```
int k = 4;
Math.sqrt(4);
```

To me there is a similar analogy  to

```
class A{}
class B extends A{}
void methodA(B someB){
}
if I try
B b= new B();
A a = new A();
b.methodA(a);    //compile error, not of right type
```

I found that this works for any method that takes in a double. Can anyone explain what's happening and why the compiler does not give you an error? Does the int get implicitly converted to a double?

I couldn't find this on any thread

Comment: Java devs thought it would be convenient to allow for automatic conversions between number types.

Comment: @popovitsj: that's incomplete. It works for widening operations (so not bi-directional) for both reference and value types (so not just 'number' types).

Answer (score -4):

*Does the int get implicitly converted to a double?*
In a way yes.

The constructor for double can take in a integer.
`double a(4);`
Hence when using `Math.sqrt(4)`, the 4 is converted to a double via the constructor. This results in the function appearing to work for integers.

You can think of it as `Math.sqrt(double(4));`

Comment: The `Double` constructor is never called in this example.

Comment: I'm sorry for downwote, but "Does the int get implicitly converted to a double?" is not "in a way yes", but exactly "yes". It's implicit conversion, read about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Comment: Did you think this was a C++ question?

Comment: Also the reasoning about implicit calling constructors when some method requires parameter of type `X` and `X` has constructor with parameter of type `Y` so method works also for parameters of type `Y` is wrong - this is not C++.